# aws-vault credentials missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get aws-vault working on my new computer.

I have a config file that looks like:

```
[profile default]
region=eu-west-1
output=json
mfa_serial = %%%
```

And a credentials file

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = %%%
aws_secret_access_key = %%%
```

but when I run

```
aws-vault exec default
```

I get the error

```
aws-vault: error: exec: Error getting temporary credentials: profile default: credentials missing
```

any ideas of how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

solved - never did `aws-vault add default`. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any credentials saved on plain text!

Anyway, I closed the current window shell and re-opened a new one, then it worked again normally on PowerShell

```
aws-vault add NAME    
aws-vault exec NAME --duration=12h -- cmd.exe
```

Just be sure you pasted correctly the credentials onto the shell

Answer (score 0):

I think what actually fixed your problem was to remove the "profile" from the `[profile default]` line in your config file. It's just `[default]` like in your credentials file. This is probably what the `aws-vault add default` command did for you.